# PWM from the Robodyn AC light dimmer

Tags: arduino, pwm, signal-processing, triac, dimmer

I am currently conducting a test on a Robodyn AC light dimmer product, and I want to check the PWM trigger output from the controller. Due to equipment limitations, I am only checking the trigger from the controller using a multimeter. Why is it that when I trigger it, there is no change in voltage? Here, I am using the output, and the voltage output can be controlled.

Comment: Welcome! Please post a schematic of your setup.

Comment: Perhaps this helps https://cmukalst.blogspot.com/2021/06/ac-light-dimmer-arduino-ac-light-dimmer.html

Comment: @winny Perhaps this helps https://cmukalst.blogspot.com/2021/06/ac-light-dimmer-arduino-ac-light-dimmer.html

Comment: Please _inline_ a schematic in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The Robotdyn AC light dimmer uses a Triac. If you use the Robotdyn library for this module, it doesn't use PWM.

For a Triac a short pulse (like 1 millisecond) is enough to make it turn on. It turns off at next zero crossing. the multimeter is not able to see that short pulse.

I have here more about that dimmer:
[https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/63631/fan-regulator-control-from-arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/63631/fan-regulator-control-from-arduino/63674#63674)

Comment: Does this mean that the library from Robodyn should function like triggering based on milliseconds of activation, similar to using a delay?

Comment: Does this mean that the library from Robodyn should function like triggering based on milliseconds of activation, similar to using a delay?